# HTML5 Application Cache - binary download

Tags: html, html5-appcache

Application Cache works well when using it to save front-end resources such as images, fonts, CSS files, JS files, etc....

I'm trying to use it to save other files, such as PDF and XLS files...

And that is where things get complicated...

I can retrieve PDF files from the App Cache with no problems, but the retrieval of XLS/XLSX files behaves in weird manners across browsers:

- Firefox 36 OSX: XLS/XLSX files can be retrieved
- Chrome 40 OSX: XLS/XLSX files can be retrieved
- Chrome 39 iOS: An error page with code 100 is displayed
- Safari 8 OSX & Safari 8.1.3 iOS: XLS/XLSX data is shown as ugly plain ASCII
- Safari 7.1.2 iOS: A popup alert is displayed saying "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"

Tests are done with Python's SimpleHTTPServer module, and every resource are valid and can be retrieved from NETWORK successfully.

It seems like RTF, DOC/DOCX and ZIP files behaves like XLS/XLSX files.

I don't understand why the binary data in a PDF file can be downloaded successfully but the others listed above can't...

Any help is welcome!

s.

Comment: Why are you really trying to do this?

Comment: I want to do an app that could deliver documents, and make them available when user is offline...

Comment: You can try using data storage solutions like indexedDB. More info [here](http://blog.iterativ.ch/2014/09/04/create-offline-web-applications-with-angularjs/)

Comment: It seems that over a year on, this is still an issue.  I'm trying to do the same, for the same kind of reasons, and note similar results.

I've only tested in Safari and Chrome on OSX. I see the same as you reported for Safari. For Chrome it appears nothing happens, though if I check the JavaScript console, the following error is shown: `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.ms-excel`.

It seems that it's only really happy with file types that can be handled by the browser itself.